# Binary search in list with generic elements

Tags: java

I have a list with custom elements and need to do a binary search through that list. However, I am getting weird results. I guess that the problem is in the compareTo method, but I don't know what I'm missing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    lista.add(new MyObject("MyObject 1"));
    lista.add(new MyObject("MyObject 2"));
    lista.add(new MyObject("MyObject 8"));
    lista.add(new MyObject("MyObject 3"));
    lista.add(new MyObject("MyObject 4"));

    int i = Collections.<MyObject>binarySearch(lista, new MyObject("MyObject 2"));
    System.out.println(i); //gives weird result if I search for the first two elements "MyObject 1" or "MyObject 2"
}


public class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {

private String sadrzaj;

public MyObject(String s) {
    this.sadrzaj = s;
}

//empty constructor, getter, setter...

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.sadrzaj;
}   

@Override
public int compareTo(MyObject o) {
    if(o.toString().equals(this.toString())) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: Your `compareTo` does not adhere to the contract of the method.

Comment: @Kidades What do you mean by weird results? Weird in what way? What exactly are you getting?

Comment: It returned -6 when searching for "My Object 2" and -5 for "My Object 1", while others gave correct results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the reference docs of Comparable.compareTo(T):

Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a `negative integer, zero, or a positive integer` as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

The implementor must ensure `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all x and y. (This implies that `x.compareTo(y)` must throw an exception `iff y.compareTo(x)` throws an exception.)

The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `(x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0`.

Finally, the implementor must ensure that `x.compareTo(y)==0` implies that `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z)), for all z`.

It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that `(x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))`. Generally speaking, any class that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is

> "Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with
>   equals."

In the foregoing description, the notation `sgn(expression)` designates the mathematical `signum` function, which is defined to return one of
`-1, 0, or 1` according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.

Where are you returning positive integer if object is greater than specified object (`MyObject`)? Also as LuiggiMendoza  ponited out Binary Search will work only if items are sorted.

Comment: Also, note that the binary search works only with a sorted array (or, to extend this concept, a sorted list). In this case, it won't work if the list is not sorted before using the binary search.

Comment: I did not know that the list has to be sorted. It now gives correct results. I've also modified the compareTo method to return correct values.